# Requirejs: AMD Module not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I want to use [datepickk.js](http://crsten.github.io/datepickk/dist/datepickk.js) inside my module: even thought this plugin supports AMD I couldn't load it inside RequireJS:
http://jsfiddle.net/numediaweb/5xbqqr0j/13/

```
// Config Object
requirejs.config({
    // Local Directory
    baseUrl: "/js",
    // Script Locations
    paths: {
        // Common Libraries
        "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min",
        "datepickk": "//crsten.github.io/datepickk/dist/datepickk.min"
    }
});

// Check Dependencies
requirejs(['jquery', 'datepickk'], function ($, Datepickk) {
    var loadedMods = require.s.contexts._.defined;
    console.log(loadedMods);
    $('#message').text('Loaded modules => '+JSON.stringify(loadedMods));
    return {};
});
```

If you check the console you will see that jquery is defined and the module not.

Any idea why this happens?

I tried another variation of loading this module:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'Datepickk': '//crsten.github.io/datepickk/dist/datepickk.min'
    },
```

But then I get this error:

```
datepickk.js:1146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at Datepickk (datepickk.js:1146)
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1693)
    at Module.check (require.js:881)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1173)
    at Module.init (require.js:786)
    at callGetModule (require.js:1200)
    at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1587)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1714)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever wrote the AMD code for `datepickk.js` needs to read up on how to write AMD modules. There are two problems:

1. **The module name is hardcoded as `Datepickk` because the `define` call is `define('Datepickk', Datepickk)`.** The first argument hardcodes the name. This is really a bad thing to do, as the RequireJS documentation is clear that developers should not hardcode names and instead let the optimizer add a name as needed, but here someone was not paying attention.

   This explains why your 2nd configuration, the one with `Datepickk` in `paths` works, but your first one does not. You must refer to it as `Datepickk` in your `paths` configuration. If you want your own code to refer to it as `datepickk`, you can use a `map` configuration in addition to `paths`:

   ```
   map: {
     "*": {
       datepickk: "Datepickk"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Yeah, even if you fix the above, you still get the error you ran into. Looking at the documentation for `Datepickk` I see that you are use it with do `new Datepickk(...)`. If you do this, then the object to be frozen should be the new object that is assigned to `this` by the JavaScript virtual machine when the constructor executes. If you look at the code that makes `Datepickk` available to other code, this is what you see:

   ```
   if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) define('Datepickk', Datepickk);
   else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) module.exports = Datepickk;
   else window.Datepickk = Datepickk;
   ```

   The 2nd and 3rd branch export the `Datepickk` constructor to the world. That's fine. The 1st branch though, which is the one that matters to you, **calls `define` with `Datepickk` acting as a module factory**. When RequireJS executes the `define` call, it *immediately* calls `Datepickk` to build the module. In this situation `this` is not set to any specific value, so it gets set to the current `Window` instance (the JavaScript virtual machine does that) and `Object.freeze` fails. The `define` call should be:

   ```
   define(function () {
       return Datepickk;
   });
   ```

   (I've also removed the hardcoded module name.) This builds a module that has for value the function `Datepickk`.

Comment: Thanks for the deep explanation: I'll make a PR for the Datepickk with your fixes and hope it gets merged.