# Can I use unpkg or browserify to include single NPM packages in a frontend project?

Tags: javascript, browserify, unpkg

So I'm working with JS on the frontend, building something for a client. Details aren't super important except that I do not have access to node.

I'm using unpkg to include various NPM packages in the browser (like React/ReactDOM/Babel for instance). These packages have a UMD build so they work out of the box.

However, there are a few packages I'd like to use that do not have a UMD build (namely react-dates or react-datepicker). I've tried serving different files via unpkg and referencing the exported modules. Since they don't have UMD builds, I'll either get an error `module is not defined` which makes sense, or that the module I'm referencing `DatePicker is not defined`.

So I thought maybe I could build a single file with browserify but I've never used it before and any docs I could find are lacking. Heres what I did

```
var DatePicker = require("react-dates");
```

In a file called test.js and then:

```
browserify test.js -o bundle.js
```

Output that, upload it to the client assets, reference it like:

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

But `var DatePicker = require("DatePicker")` throws error `require is not defined` (I thought that was the point of browserify?) and `console.log(DatePicker)` throws `is not defined` as well.

At this point I'm at a loss. I'm being stubborn but I really really just want to use a react datepicker and avoid adding jQuery to this project for the sole purpose of a datepicker. As far as I can tell unpkg is not an option but I feel like browserify could work and I'm just doing something wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: your bundle should not have the require statement in it .. are you sure that the require statement is correct? either you have a directory with that name and capital letters, and index.js in it, or a DatePicker.js, .. or a node_modules/DatePicker.js -- with that case spelling? https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-browserify

Comment: I don't know what you mean? The `var DatePicker = require("DatePicker")` is in  a script tag in the browser.  `var DatePicker = require("react-dates");` is in my bundle.js. I tried `var DatePicker = require("bundle")` in the browser but that didn't work either still throws `require is not defined`.  I read through that tutorial prior, but it's still not working. I think the issue is because I'm trying to use this to bundle a single library and make it work with a bunch of script tags but I'm not sure. Do I need both react-dates.js and bundle.js included in my html?

Comment: If you were using react-datepicker then change the require statement to `require('react-datepicker')`  PS I see you've changed the statement already but 1 the library must be installed and 2 you must reference it by node's name for it (which it looks like you've done with react-dates

Comment: I'm not working in node, that is the issue

Comment: since I'm in the browser I do not have access to CommonJS

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do this, you can find the needed files in the dist folder (***New folder*\node_modules\react-datepicker**) after you "npm install react-datepicker" within a folder, but be sure you have a package file into that, otherwise the install won't work.

The files should look like this

[image]

EDIT:

The requirejs code that you need is

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>

<script>
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react',
            'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom',
            'prop-types': 'https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.0/prop-types',
            'react-onclickoutside': 'https://unpkg.com/react-onclickoutside@6.7.0/dist/react-onclickoutside',
            'react-popper': 'https://unpkg.com/react-popper@0.7.4/dist/react-popper',
            'moment': 'https://unpkg.com/moment@2.19.3/moment',
            'datepicker': 'https://unpkg.com/react-datepicker@0.61.0/dist/react-datepicker'
        }
    });

    requirejs(['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types', 'react-onclickoutside', 'react-popper', 'moment', 'datepicker'], function(React, ReactDOM, PropTypes, onClickOutside, Popper, moment, DatePicker) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement('p', {}, 'Hello, World!'),
            document.getElementById('root')
        )
    });
```

but as far as I got, datepicker requested for "module" which is not defined, this can be the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808397/requirejs-amd-module-not-defined). I will investigate more about this issue.

Comment: `but be sure you have a package file into that` what do you mean by this? a package.json?

Comment: yes, you can use "npm init"; it will generate one for you, but you'll also have to provide some details about the package...just add dummy data

Comment: so I did that, moved the entire `dist` folder to my clients assets, then loaded `script src="react-datepicker-min.js"` and `link href="react-datepicker.css"` but I'm still getting `ReactDatePicker is not defined` or `DatePicker is not defined` etc. Did I do something wrong?